# instant auto fill input form based in from another input

Tags: jquery

Hi i would like to auto fill 2 input form based in from another input.. so far i tried it like this and its working

but it is possible the change to the two input is live/instant and without pressing enter ?

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#totalofservices').change(function(){
         $("#totalontarget").attr('value',$(this).val());
         $("#totalontarget").attr('value',$(this).val());
     });
   });
 </script>

<input style='text-align:center' class='form-control' type='text' size='20' id='totalofservices' name='totalofservices'>
<input style='text-align:center' class='form-control' type='text' size='20' id='totalontarget' name='totalontarget'>
<input style='text-align:center' class='form-control' type='text' size='20' id='totalofftarget' name='totalfftarget'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code, it will update the two fields when you type-in the first field:

```
 $('#totalofservices').keyup(function(){
     $("#totalontarget, #totalfftarget").val($(this).val());
 });
```

Comment: Thank you..this is what i want

Comment: @gtroop I answered first, anyway, great that you got it. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You did something right but not everything. Use the `.val()` again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#totalofservices').change(function(){
    $("#totalontarget").val($(this).val());
    $("#totalontarget").val($(this).val());
  });
});
```